# How do I unnest a data.table nested field?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to unnest a nested field in data.table:

```
name <- c("AAA", "AAA" ,"BBB")
desc<- c("desc_AAA", "desc_AAA","desc_BBB")
nested_field <- list(list(brand = "brand_1", model = "model_1"),
                     list(brand = "brand_2", model = "model_2"),
                     list(brand = "brand_3", model = "model_3"))
dt <- data.table(name, desc,nested_field)
```

I tried:

```
out <- dt [, lapply(nested_field, unlist, recursive = F), by =.(name, desc)]
```

and got error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , lapply(nested_field, unlist, recursive = F),  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group
```

instead of the desired output:

```
1 AAA   desc_AAA brand_1 model_1
2 AAA   desc_AAA brand_2 model_2
3 BBB   desc_BBB brand_3 model_3
```

How do I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `data.table::rbindlist()`

```
data.table( name, desc, rbindlist( nested_field ) )
```

which results in

```
   name     desc   brand   model
1:  AAA desc_AAA brand_1 model_1
2:  AAA desc_AAA brand_2 model_2
3:  BBB desc_BBB brand_3 model_3
```

Comment: Great, thank you Wimpel, Actually, the object I have is a large dt itself. How would I apply rindlist directly from dt?

Comment: You can add the columns from the data.table created with rbindlist using `cbind()`.

Answer (score 2):

The code that best fits my case is

```
out <- data.table(dt[,1:2], rbindlist(dt[[3]]))
```